# Create a subset that is balanced across multiple variables

Tags: r, subset

To illustrate my question, a dummy example: I have a data set with 16 rows (these represent trials) and 3 columns (trial difficulty, label X, and label Y).  Label X is a factor with 4 levels (1–4), and label Y is a factor with 2 levels ("female", "male").  For example:

```
        difficulty    X    Y
trial1   3.0           1    male
trial2   1.4           1    male
trial3   2.1           1    female
trial4   1.5           1    female
trial5   0.3           2    male
trial6   1.2           2    male
trial7   3.0           2    female
trial8   1.6           2    female
trial9   0.8           3    male
trial10  1.4           3    male
trial11  2.8           3    female
trial12  1.5           3    female
trial13  0.3           4    male
trial14  1.2           4    male
trial15  3.0           4    female
trial16  1.6           4    female
```

I should like to create a subset of 8 trials from the total of 16 trials; a subset that should adhere to the following criteria:

1. there is an equal number of trials within the four levels of label X
2. there is an equal number of trials within the two levels of label Y (and there should also be an equal number of trials for each level of label Y within the four levels of label X)
3. the trial difficulty variable (numeric, ranging from 0 to 3) should be as close as possible to 1.5

For my example, the ideal set in this dummy example would be:

```
        difficulty    X    Y
trial2   1.4           1    male
trial4   1.5           1    female
trial6   1.2           2    male
trial8   1.6           2    female
trial10  1.4           3    male
trial12  1.5           3    female
trial14  1.2           4    male
trial16  1.6           4    female
```

This subset has 2 trials per level of X, and an equal number of females and males for each level of X, while all trials have a difficulty value that is as close as possible to 1.5.

My attempts have been to use many nested `while` and `if` loops, but am not sure how to check for two variables at the same time (at the moment I'm looping until X is fulfilled, then looping until Y is fulfilled, then looping until X is fulfilled again, etc.).  Would this be the right approach, or would there be a more sensible way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code assumes your data frame is called `dat`. The code adds a new variable `difficulty.scaled` equal to the deviation of `difficulty` from 1.5, then groups the data by values of X and Y, and then selects the observations within each group with absolute value of `difficulty.scaled` closest to 0 (i.e., `difficulty` closest to 1.5).

You can adjust the `probs` argument to the `quantile` function to select whatever percentage of each subgroup that you want. In this case, I've selected 50% of the rows in each subgroup (that is, 50% of the rows representing each combination of `X` and `Y`).

```
library(dplyr)  # Install the dplyr package if you don't already have it
dat2 = dat %.%
         mutate(difficulty.scaled=difficulty - 1.5) %.%
         group_by(X, Y) %.%
         filter(abs(difficulty.scaled) < quantile(abs(difficulty.scaled), .5))
```

For the data you pasted in above (where I've converted the trial number to a variable), here's the output:

```
     tnum difficulty X      Y difficulty.scaled
1  trial2        1.4 1   male              -0.1
2  trial4        1.5 1 female               0.0
3  trial6        1.2 2   male              -0.3
4  trial8        1.6 2 female               0.1
5 trial10        1.4 3   male              -0.1
6 trial12        1.5 3 female               0.0
7 trial14        1.2 4   male              -0.3
8 trial16        1.6 4 female               0.1
```

The data you provided has equal numbers of observations for each combination of `X` and `Y`. If your real data are unbalanced on these variables, then instead of selecting a percentage of the rows in each sub-group, you can select a specific number of rows. The code below selects the `n` rows with the lowest absolute value of `difficulty.scaled` in each sub-group. That way your subset will be balanced even if your full data set is not (as long as you have at least `n` rows of data for each combination of `X` and `Y`).

```
n=1
dat2 = dat %.%
         mutate(difficulty.scaled=difficulty - 1.5) %.%
         group_by(X, Y) %.%
         filter(rank(abs(difficulty.scaled), ties.method="first") <= n)
```

`ties.method="first"` ensures that exactly `n` rows will be returned, even if there is more than one row with the same absolute value of `difficulty.scaled`.

**Update: How to divide subsetted data into training and test sets.**

Assuming `dat2` is your balanced subset, you can divide it into training and test subsets as follows:

```
# Note that you need to use %>% instead of %.%
train = dat2 %>%
  do(sample_n(., 10))
```

This will return 10 randomly sampled rows per sub-group. Just set this value to whatever number of rows per sub-group you want in your training sample. Notice that you don't need to group by X and Y to create the training sample. This is because when you created `dat2`, `dplyr` added grouping attributes to `dat2` that `dplyr` continues to recognize. Do `str(dat2)` to see this.

`do` is a generic function that allows you to perform arbitrary operations on a data frame from within `dplyr`. The period `.` is kind of a "pronoun" that represents the data frame (`dat2` in this case). This will only work with `%>%` instead of `%.%`. (`dplyr` is in active development and is transitioning from `%.%` to `%>%` for chaining operations, so it's probably best to just use `%>%` from now on.)

```
# The test set then includes all rows that are not part of train. 
# Since tnum has a unique value for each row, use tnum to select all rows that 
# are not part of train.
test = dat2[!(dat2$tnum %in% train$tnum), ]
```

Comment: This is bang on – excellent!  Hadn't come across the `dplyr` package before.  One small addition: how can I save the result in a new variable?  Adding `dat2 <- ` at the beginning of the final line breaks the code.

Comment: See updated answer. Think of `a %.% b %.% c %.% d` as a single `R` statement. It's the equivalent of `d(c(b(a))))`, but easier to understand. There are many ways to do what you wanted to do in `R`. I find `dplyr` very intuitive, so that's the approach I decided to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes a lot of sense and is actually a very clear way of coding.  One final question: how can I now split this subset into two equal sets (for test-retest), while again both sets adhere to the same constraints? Perhaps ranking `difficulty.scaled` and taking every second trial, while simultaneously satisfying the X and Y constraints?  I tried changing `n` but don't fully understand how it is used (`c(1,3,5,7)` doesn't work for instance).

Comment: `rank` returns a vector giving the rank (from 1 to M, where M is the number of values in the sub-group) of each absolute value of `difficulty.scaled`. `n` just tells filter to select the first `n` rank values from that vector. Try the following to see what's going on: `x=c(20,10,60,40)`. `rank(x)`. `x[rank(x) <= 2]`

Comment: As for how to create training and test subsets, see updated answer.

Comment: Somehow `train = dat2 %>%
  do(sample_n(., 10)) ` returns `Error: could not find function "%>%"`; if I then use `%.%` it returns `Error: expecting a single value`, regardless of the size of `n`?

Comment: You might need to use the development version of `dplyr`. Run the following and you should be okay: `install.packages('devtools')`, `library(devtools)`, `install_github(repo='dplyr', user='hadley')`, `library(dplyr)`. I expect these features will be in the regular release of `dplyr` soon.